# Using convoluted in a sentence

Tags: word-usage, word-meaning

Does this sentence make sense?

> But in my view, it is one ability that had been most abused and **convoluted**, as we human being continue to juggle and keep up with the fast pace of changing times.

or I can replace the use of *convoluted* as:

> But in my view, it is one ability that had been most abused and **has been the least understood**, as we human being continue to juggle and keep up with the fast pace of changing times.

Comment: Both are convoluted indeed. What ability? Human being**s**. The broader context is needed

Comment: *Convoluted* doesn't mean the same thing as *least understood*, so I'm not sure what you're trying to say.  In general, you can't use *convoluted* that way, with the passive voice: we just say that something *is* convoluted, not that it *has been* convoluted (by somebody else).

Comment: @stangdon [Why not?](https://www.google.ru/search?newwindow=1&dcr=0&ei=jx8CWtu4GMPF6ATc6YKIAg&q=%22has+been+convoluted+by+the%22&oq=%22has+been+convoluted+by+the%22&gs_l=psy-ab.12...19120.21302.0.23213.9.9.0.0.0.0.88.623.9.9.0....0...1.1.64.psy-ab..0.0.0....0.m1AixKehJsI) _Has the form of a snail shell been convoluted by the Creator of by evolution?_

Comment: @MvLog - Perhaps I should have said we generally *don't* use "convoluted" that way.  I mean, saying that the Creator...convolved?...the snail shell sounds even weirder.

Comment: @MV Log Let me tell you the context. I Was talking about Multitasking as an ability.

Answer (score 1):

You can replace the one sentence with the other (as MV Log points out, however, "human beings" is correct, not "human being"), but the sentences have different meanings.

If you are asking whether "convoluted" has the meaning of "least understood," the answer is no. In this sense, "convoluted" means complicated and therefore hard to understand. While convoluted ideas are often hard to understand, simple ideas can be more so.

This is a convoluted idea:

> When scholars use language in unexpected and difficult ways, people who read what is written are forced to stop in their tracks and rethink ideas and worldviews that they've always taken for granted. - Judith Butler

This is not a convoluted idea, but it is more difficult to understand:

> The wise man keeps to the deed that takes no action. - Lao Tzu

Comment: Thanks for detailed answer! No I am not looking for similar meaning phrases. I was looking to see if it makes sense to use the word convoluted in that sentence. I am talking about Multitasking as an ability actually. If convoluted doesn't work then I would use least understood. Both can fulfill the requirement although different meanings. Also thank you for pointing out about 'human beings' :)

Comment: @Shumaila Multitasking? I might say that the prevailing understanding of multitasking has become convoluted, given the range of opinions about its value.